# NSFetchedResultsController performFetch doesn't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have segmented control on the screen. 1 segmented item is for Ads (Ads table) and the 2nd segmented item is for Orders (Orders table).
Each time when user selects the segmented item, I recreate the instance of NSFetchResultController with new fetch request to another data table (but on UI I always have only one UITableView `self.tableViewMain`):

```
let entityName = screen == ProfileScreen.Ads ? kDB_entity_DBAd : kDB_entity_DBOrder
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext)
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
do {
    try fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
} catch {
    print("An error occurred in fetchresultcontroller")
}
```

But first time it reloads data correctly, but second time fetchresultcontroller even doesn't reload table (`numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath` are not called). So the second time new instance of NSFetchResultController (which is related to the second table in core data) doesn't do anything when I call `fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `tableViewMain.reloadData()` to get the table to reload itself.